# How can I pass extra options to Node in Meteor's HTTP.call()?

Tags: node.js, ssl, meteor, runtime-error

I'm getting an [SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461979/node-js-error-with-ssl-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature) when doing an HTTP.get() call in Meteor, [UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200391/nodejs-unable-to-verify-leaf-signature).

The links above point to solutions involving Node parameters (for instance `{rejectUnauthorized: false}`), but it's unclear how to pass any of those to Meteor. I've tried `HTTP.get(url, {rejectUnauthorized: false})` without luck.

Comment: If you check the URL against http://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html what do you get? You could also use a http link instead of the https link. This error usually happens when the certificate is invalid for the domain

Comment: @Akshat: Just checked the URL and the problem was fixed server-side. Thanks for that resource! (the http link redirected to the https one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's now possible by passing [npmRequestOptions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1703#issuecomment-168599488) to Meteor HTTP requests:

```
  const requestOptions = {
    npmRequestOptions: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
  const result = HTTP.get(url, requestOptions)
```

Comment: Took them a while.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a fork of Meteor's HTTP package, which just passes through options it doesn't know about. I think it's a sane thing to do (instead of discarding the options entirely), and I hope the Meteor team pulls [the change](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1703) into core.

The Atmosphere package is called [http-more](http://beta.atmospherejs.com/package/http-more).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of the HTTP package (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/http/httpcall_server.js#L75), I noticed that it isn't implemented using node's http class directly, but instead uses the `request` package and the options you can pass it (see line in above link) are limited. So I'm not sure this is currently possible.

Looking at the `request` package's request options (https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback) I wouldn't be sure how to enable the option you care about either.

BTW, if you are on the server, you can always use http(s) directly using `Npm.require('https')`.

Comment: One could indeed use Npm's `http` but then you have reinvent the entire wheel that the HTTP Meteor package has put around it. Why do that when all it takes for Meteor to enable this option is [one line of code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1703)?